# My code for addClass and removeClass doesnt seem to work with Bootstrap Glyphicons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Recently,** I decided to experiment with bootstrap's glyphicons. And using Jquery's `addClass` and `removeClass` properties, I attempted to effectively switch from one glyphicon to another.

**Here is the code snippet:**

```js
var glyphOn = true; //Ok, glyphOn is a boolean variable to keep track whether .navList is visible or not.

$('.glyphicon').click(function() {
  if (glyphOn == true) {
    $('.navList').fadeIn(500).addClass('glyphicon-remove').removeClass('glyphicon-align-justify');

    glyphOn = false;
  } else {
    $('.navList').fadeOut(500);
    glyphOn = true;
  }
});
```

```css
/*This CSS is mainly for demonstration purposes, so I believe this can be ignored. The only thing that can be noticed here is that .navList has display:none;*/

.glyphicon {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.navList {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--This is a sample example using two commonly used glyphicons used in Mobile Web Development.-->
<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"><!--According to the bootstrap documentation, I should leave the content inside this tag completely empty.--></span>
</p>
<ul class="navList">
  <li>List Item 1</li>
  <li>List Item 2</li>
  <li>List Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Now, I'm sorry if this is a simple problem, but I have searched the web for a solution, but I have been unsuccessful.

For clarification I will declare the goal and problem:

**GOAL:** To efficiently find a way to switch glyphicons inside of an element.(In this case: switch between a Mobile Menu Glyph to an Exit Glyph.)

**PROBLEM**The code snippet that I have coded does not work as expected.

And Thank You in advance to whoever comments and answers :)

Comment: You're adding the `glyphicon-remove` class to `navList` instead of `glyphicon`

Comment: Thanks to everyone for there answers and comments :) As of right now I'm still deciding on which answer to choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var glyphOn = true; //Ok, glyphOn is a boolean variable to keep track whether .navList is visible or not.

$('.glyphicon').click(function() {
  if (glyphOn == true) {
    $('.navList').fadeIn(500);
    $(this).addClass('glyphicon-remove').removeClass('glyphicon-align-justify');

    glyphOn = false;
  } else {
    $('.navList').fadeOut(500);
    $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-align-justify');
    glyphOn = true;
  }
});
```

The mistake you're making, asp pointed out by Khalid in the comments, is that you're changing class to the ul element instead of the glyphicon one (which is above stated as "this" since it's the one clicked to trigger the function).

I tried to answer editing the code as less as I could, but I'd suggest you to use, instead of global variables, a listener to the class of the glyphicon element to accomplish the same result, or even better, to toggle "remove" and "align-justify" classes accordingly like in the example below.

```
$('.glyphicon').click(function() {
  $('.navList').fadeToggle(500);
  $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-remove').toggleClass('glyphicon-align-justify');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer works effectively and as expected. Moreover, you provided a useful correction on the bottom of your answer.(thank you for that :))Anyway, thanks, and I believe your answer is the most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `glyphicon-remove` by `glyphicon`, it should work

```
$('.glyphicon').click(function () {
     if (glyphOn == true) {
        $('.navList').fadeIn(500).addClass('glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-align-justify');

        glyphOn = false;
     }else{
        $('.navList').fadeOut(500);
        glyphOn = true;
     }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts David, but this wasn't what I was looking for. But thank you though :)

Answer (score 1):

try with this code

i've put mnIcon class to span and in js i've use the addClass and removeClass for span not ul navList.

```js
var glyphOn = true;//Ok, glyphOn is a boolean variable to keep track whether .navList is visible or not.
    $('.glyphicon').click(function () {
      if (glyphOn == true) {
      $('.navList').fadeIn(500);
      $('.mnIcon').removeClass('glyphicon-align-justify');
      $('.mnIcon').addClass('glyphicon-remove'); 
      glyphOn = false;
        } else {
       $('.navList').fadeOut(500);
   $('.mnIcon').removeClass('glyphicon-remove'); 
       $('.mnIcon').addClass('glyphicon-align-justify');
       glyphOn = true;
      }
    });
```

```css
/*This CSS is mainly for demonstration purposes, so I believe this can be ignored. The only thing that can be noticed here is that .navList has display:none;*/
 .glyphicon {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 .navList {
    display: none;
   }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><span class="mnIcon glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"><!--According to the bootstrap documentation, I should leave the content inside this tag completely empty.--></span></p>
<ul class="navList">
  <li>List Item 1</li>
  <li>List Item 2</li>
  <li>List Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the class to the clicked menu, not to the list: Below code works:

```
$('.glyphicon').click(function() {
      if (glyphOn == true) {
        $('.navList').fadeIn(500);
$(this).addClass('glyphicon-remove').removeClass('glyphicon-align-justify');

        glyphOn = false;
      } else {
        $('.navList').fadeOut(500);
$(this).addClass('glyphicon-align-justify').removeClass('glyphicon-remove');
        glyphOn = true;
      }
    });
```